# My html form not responding to js validation and html required

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

Every time I submit the form even when the form is empty it take me to my controller.

It doesn't validate the html form with required and it doesn't respond on javascript validation onsubmit. I have tried on the submit button onclick still the same problem.

The confusing part is that the input required not even working either `required="required"` or `required`.

The only validation that is working is the `type="email"` and `type="number"` the rest nothing.

I check my js file it works fine.

Thank you

```js
/*----------------------VALIDATION INPUT REGISTRATION FORM---------------------*/
function validate_register_form() {
  var first_name          = document.forms["register_form"]["first_name"].value;
  var last_name           = document.forms["register_form"]["last_name"].value;
  var email               = document.forms["register_form"]["email"].value;
  var password            = document.forms["register_form"]["password"].value;
  var retype_password     = document.forms["register_form"]["retype_password"].value;
  var mobile_number       = document.forms["register_form"]["mobile_number"].value;
  var gender              = document.forms["register_form"]["gender"].value;
  var p_b                 = document.forms["register_form"]["p_b"].value;
  var privacy             = document.forms["register_form"]["one"].value;


  if(first_name == null || first_name == "") {
   document.getElementById('first_name').style.borderColor = "red";
   alert("First Name must be filled out");
   return false;
 }else{
   document.getElementById('first_name').style.borderColor = "green";
 }



 if(last_name == null || last_name == "") {
   document.getElementById('last_name').style.borderColor = "red";
   alert("Last Name must be filled out");
   return false;
 }else{
   document.getElementById('last_name').style.borderColor = "green";
 }

 if(email == null || email == ""){
   document.getElementById('email').style.borderColor = "red";
   alert("Email must be filled out");
   return false;
 }else{
   document.getElementById('email').style.borderColor = "green";
 }


 if(password == null || password == ""){
   document.getElementById('password').style.borderColor = "red";
   alert("Password must be filled out");
   return false;
 }else{
   document.getElementById('password').style.borderColor = "green";
 }

 if(retype_password == null || retype_password == ""){
   document.getElementById('retype_password').style.borderColor = "red";
   alert("retype password must be filled out");
   return false;
 }else{
   document.getElementById('retype_password').style.borderColor = "green";
 }

 if(password != retype_password){
   document.getElementById('password').style.borderColor = "red";
   document.getElementById('retype_password').style.borderColor = "red";
   alert("password not match");
   return false;
 }else{
   document.getElementById('password').style.borderColor = "green";
   document.getElementById('retype_password').style.borderColor = "green";
 }

 if(mobile_number == null || mobile_number == ""){
   document.getElementById('mobile_number').style.borderColor = "red";
   alert("Mobile number must be filled out");
   return false;
 }else{
   document.getElementById('mobile_number').style.borderColor = "green";
 }

 if(gender == null || gender == ""){
   document.getElementById('gender').style.borderColor = "red";
   alert("Gender must me filled out");
   return false;
 }else{
   document.getElementById('gender').style.borderColor = "green";
 }

 if(p_b == null || p_b == ""){
   document.getElementById('p_b').style.borderColor = "red";
   alert("Persoanl or Dealer must be filled out");
   return false;
 }else{
   document.getElementById('p_b').style.borderColor = "green";
 }

 if(privacy == null || privacy == "" || privacy != "on"){
   document.getElementById('privacy').style.borderColor = "red";
   alert("Privacy must be checked in order to submit the form");
   return false;
 }else{
   document.getElementById('privacy').style.borderColor = "green";
 }


return true;

} // end of registration validation form registration.php
```

```html
 <form  action="controllers/core.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate_register_form(this);">
      <div class="gray-form" id="register_form">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="form-group col-md-6">
           <label>Your Name*</label>
           <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" name="first_name" id="first_name" required />
         </div> 
         <div class="form-group col-md-6">
           <label>Last Name*</label>
           <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name" id="last_name" required />
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <label>Email *</label>
         <input  class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" name="email" id="email" required />
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <label>Password* </label>
         <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" required />
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <label>Re-enter Password*</label>
         <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="retype_password" id="retype_password" required />
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <label>Mobile phone *</label>
         <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Enter your mobile no" id="mobile_number" name="mobile_number" required />
       </div>

       <div class="form-group">
         <label>Gender *</label>
         <div class="selected-box">
          <select name="gender" id="gender" class="form-control">
            <option value="">I am</option>
            <option  value="male">male</option>
            <option  value="female">Female</option>
            <option  value="Business">Business</option>
          </select>
        </div> 
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label>Personal or Dealer *</label>
       <div class="selected-box">
        <select name="p_b"  id="p_b" class="form-control">
          <option  value="">I am looking for a </option>
          <option  value="personal">Personal Account</option>
          <option  value="dealer">Dealer Account</option>
        </select>
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="remember-checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox" name="privacy" id="one"  />
       <label for="one">Accept our <a href="#"> privacy policy</a> and <a href="#"> customer agreement</a></label>
     </div>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="button red"  name="register"> Register an account </button>
   <p class="link">Already have an account? please <a href="?controller=page&action=login"> login here </a></p>
 </div>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added a name attribute to the **form**, and remove `required` from every field, required will be the basic HTML validation so no need of that in your custom validation method.

```
<form  action="controllers/core.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate_register_form(this);" name='register_form'>
```

```js
/*----------------------VALIDATION INPUT REGISTRATION FORM---------------------*/
function validate_register_form() {
  var first_name          = document.forms["register_form"]["first_name"].value;
  var last_name           = document.forms["register_form"]["last_name"].value;
  var email               = document.forms["register_form"]["email"].value;
  var password            = document.forms["register_form"]["password"].value;
  var retype_password     = document.forms["register_form"]["retype_password"].value;
  var mobile_number       = document.forms["register_form"]["mobile_number"].value;
  var gender              = document.forms["register_form"]["gender"].value;
  var p_b                 = document.forms["register_form"]["p_b"].value;
  var privacy             = document.forms["register_form"]["one"].value;


  if(first_name == null || first_name == "") {
   document.getElementById('first_name').style.borderColor = "red";
   alert("First Name must be filled out");
   return false;
 }else{
   document.getElementById('first_name').style.borderColor = "green";
 }



 if(last_name == null || last_name == "") {
   document.getElementById('last_name').style.borderColor = "red";
   alert("Last Name must be filled out");
   return false;
 }else{
   document.getElementById('last_name').style.borderColor = "green";
 }

 if(email == null || email == ""){
   document.getElementById('email').style.borderColor = "red";
   alert("Email must be filled out");
   return false;
 }else{
   document.getElementById('email').style.borderColor = "green";
 }


 if(password == null || password == ""){
   document.getElementById('password').style.borderColor = "red";
   alert("Password must be filled out");
   return false;
 }else{
   document.getElementById('password').style.borderColor = "green";
 }

 if(retype_password == null || retype_password == ""){
   document.getElementById('retype_password').style.borderColor = "red";
   alert("retype password must be filled out");
   return false;
 }else{
   document.getElementById('retype_password').style.borderColor = "green";
 }

 if(password != retype_password){
   document.getElementById('password').style.borderColor = "red";
   document.getElementById('retype_password').style.borderColor = "red";
   alert("password not match");
   return false;
 }else{
   document.getElementById('password').style.borderColor = "green";
   document.getElementById('retype_password').style.borderColor = "green";
 }

 if(mobile_number == null || mobile_number == ""){
   document.getElementById('mobile_number').style.borderColor = "red";
   alert("Mobile number must be filled out");
   return false;
 }else{
   document.getElementById('mobile_number').style.borderColor = "green";
 }

 if(gender == null || gender == ""){
   document.getElementById('gender').style.borderColor = "red";
   alert("Gender must me filled out");
   return false;
 }else{
   document.getElementById('gender').style.borderColor = "green";
 }

 if(p_b == null || p_b == ""){
   document.getElementById('p_b').style.borderColor = "red";
   alert("Persoanl or Dealer must be filled out");
   return false;
 }else{
   document.getElementById('p_b').style.borderColor = "green";
 }

 if(privacy == null || privacy == "" || privacy != "on"){
   document.getElementById('privacy').style.borderColor = "red";
   alert("Privacy must be checked in order to submit the form");
   return false;
 }else{
   document.getElementById('privacy').style.borderColor = "green";
 }


return true;

} // end of registration validation form registration.php
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form  action="controllers/core.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validate_register_form(this);" name='register_form'>
      <div class="gray-form" id="register_form">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="form-group col-md-6">
           <label>Your Name*</label>
           <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" name="first_name" id="first_name" />
         </div> 
         <div class="form-group col-md-6">
           <label>Last Name*</label>
           <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name" id="last_name" />
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <label>Email *</label>
         <input  class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" name="email" id="email" />
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <label>Password* </label>
         <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" />
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <label>Re-enter Password*</label>
         <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="retype_password" id="retype_password" />
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
         <label>Mobile phone *</label>
         <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Enter your mobile no" id="mobile_number" name="mobile_number" />
       </div>

       <div class="form-group">
         <label>Gender *</label>
         <div class="selected-box">
          <select name="gender" id="gender" class="form-control">
            <option value="">I am</option>
            <option  value="male">male</option>
            <option  value="female">Female</option>
            <option  value="Business">Business</option>
          </select>
        </div> 
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label>Personal or Dealer *</label>
       <div class="selected-box">
        <select name="p_b"  id="p_b" class="form-control">
          <option  value="">I am looking for a </option>
          <option  value="personal">Personal Account</option>
          <option  value="dealer">Dealer Account</option>
        </select>
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="remember-checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox" name="privacy" id="one"  />
       <label for="one">Accept our <a href="#"> privacy policy</a> and <a href="#"> customer agreement</a></label>
     </div>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="button red"  name="register"> Register an account </button>
   <p class="link">Already have an account? please <a href="?controller=page&action=login"> login here </a></p>
 </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Please update the code in question and check in a console, if there is an error or something because the code is working fine in the snippet I guess. @CharbelMhanna

Comment: thank you . After checking my console had a problem element id that I rechange. Now I put back your code it works perfectly.